# Deploy laravel 5.2 FTP

Tags: laravel-5, ftp, deploy, cache, ssh

Publiquei meu primeiro projeto laravel via FTP, para entender como funciona a estrutura dentro de um servidor.

Subi tudo dentro da pasta www e criei um .htaccess na raiz para referenciar a pasta public do laravel, até aqui tudo correto.

O problema que ocorre é que algumas configurações vieram do projeto local, por exemplo o caminho das views, me forçando a rodar o comando php artisan config:cache, que resolveu o problema. Porém não será em todos os servidores que terei acesso via ssh, como posso solucionar este problema de cache, somente utilizando o FTP?

Comment: O ideal é sua aplicação ficar fora do www e renomear o www para a pasta public. Configurando o server dessa forma não deve ter maiores problema. Se não é possível configurar o server a esse ponto, talvez seja uma boa ideia rever sua hospedagem.